# Open Reason Re-fills outside of Reason

Tags: software, daw

Is there any program that can open Reason's refill files? Other than Reason of course. 
I would potentially like to use some of the samples contained within the Reason refill in another DAW.

Answer (score 2):

I'm unaware of any, but the traditional approach to this is to load them in Reason, and then connect Reason to any other app using ReWire. Reason then, essentially, acts like a hardware box connected to an input and output.